# My site admin panel redirecting automatically to my other site admin panel in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web

I go to mysite.net/wp-admin. Once I type in my username and pass word it redirects me to a blank page with address of

```
mysite.co.uk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.net%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I own both domains mysite.co.uk and mysite.net. in fact mysite.co.uk redirects to mysite.net

Comment: There is redicect in your functions.php file of theme or may be in .htacess file. And also check your database site_url and home_url

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database, and find the table called wp-option, then change the WordPress address and site address to mysite.net.

You can also add the following lines of code to the wp-config.php file

```
Define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-site-url.com');
Define('WP_HOME','http://your-site-url.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your mysite.net website's file manager,

go to your functions.php file and insert the below code at the very top:

```
<?php 
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://your-site-url' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://your-site-url' );
//Replace your-site-url with your site url eg: mysite.net
?>
```

after inserting this code try to refresh your site.